# How can I custom my Event ID of Google Calendar when I input new event with Google Calendar API Python?

Tags: python, insert, google-calendar-api, event-id

I want to insert Event ID that I want, to Google Calendar API with Python, 
but I don't know how to do it,

```
 event = {
      'summary': acara,
      'location': lokasi,
      'description': deskripsi,
      'start': {
        'dateTime': start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
        'timeZone': timezone,
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
        'timeZone': timezone,
      },


      'attendees': attendees,

      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': False,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can specify your custom event Id by simply adding the field `id` to the event resource:

```
 event = {
      'id': 123456
      'summary': acara,
      'location': lokasi,
      'description': deskripsi,
      'start': {
        'dateTime': start_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
        'timeZone': timezone,
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
        'timeZone': timezone,
      },


      'attendees': attendees,

      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': False,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
      },
    }
```

**Important**

The event id needs to fulfill certain criteria as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body):

> When creating new single or recurring
> events, you can specify their IDs. Provided IDs must follow these
> rules:
>
> characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex
> encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2
> in RFC2938
>
> the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
>
> the ID must be unique per calendar
>
> Due to the globally distributed
> nature of the system, we cannot guarantee that ID collisions will be
> detected at event creation time. To minimize the risk of collisions we
> recommend using an established UUID algorithm such as one described in
> RFC4122.
>
> If you do not specify an ID, it will be automatically
> generated by the server.
>
> Note that the icalUID and the id are not identical and only one of
> them should be supplied at event creation time. One difference in
> their semantics is that in recurring events, all occurrences of one
> event have different ids while they all share the same icalUIDs.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Events: insert". You can see the detail [here.](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#python)

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

source: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#python

Comment: Pings don't work like this. If you want to talk to the moderator you can use the `flag` button under any post and **clearly** explain what action you want them to take and why.

Comment: Perhaps a better and more candid approach altogether would be to explain the events in a new [meta] post and reason about your apparent switch from aggressive to humble. Barring that, perhaps the simplest way forward is to abandon the deleted post and just start over with a new, fresh question.

Comment: Hmmm, that complicates matters. Improving your rep to the point where you escape the ban would be the first step then.

Comment: @Dharman Could you elaborate why this answer would have a downvote? It very specifically answers the question.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has a downvote. Maybe someone who read it thought it was not enough of an explanation of the problem. Try to add some explanation and teach the question asker how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: @Dharman explain it? "I want to insert Event ID that I want, to Google Calendar API with Python, but I don't know how to do it", I can't really explain it as it's googles events?

Answer (score 0):

Just a self-plug:

There is the [Google Calendar Simple API](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/Google-Calendar-Simple-API) for Python (written by me). It is much simpler and more Pythonic, object-oriented. It handles credentials, JSON formatting, datetimes/timezones, recurrence, etc. for you. Here is the [Documentation](https://google-calendar-simple-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest).

And you would use it as:

```
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar
from gcsa.event import Event

calendar = GoogleCalendar('your_email@gmail.com')
event = Event(
    summary=acara,
    event_id=your_id,
    start=start_date,
    end=end_time,
    timezone=timezone,
    attendees=attendees,
    recurrence=Recurrence.rule(freq=DAILY)),
    minutes_before_email_reminder=24 * 60,
    minutes_before_popup_reminder=10
)

calendar.add_event(event)
```